# How to link_to a particular part of a page using a class Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, link-to

I have a navigation and for certain parts, I'd like to `link_to` a particular sections of the page when it is navigated to it.

I tried this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Submit Data", about_path(anchor: "submit-data") %>
```

but I ended up on the correct about page but not to the section I desired.  The submit-data div is lower on the about page. Is this more complex than I think it is?  Please send examples.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<%= link_to "Submit Data", "#{about_path}#The_SECTION_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_TRAVERSE_TO" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing submit-data to an id instead of a class.  The above link_to worked when I did this action.

Answer (score 0):

Typically anchors (the #my_anchor_name part of a URL) cause the scroll position of the page to move to a corresponding anchor target in the markup.

The anchor targets are written as:

```
<a name="my_anchor_name"></a>
```

You can put headers inside if you want as well, for clean formatting:

```
<a name="my_anchor_name"><h1>Submit Your Data Here</h1></a>
```